# ASP:DropDownList To bind or not to bind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it better to bind a large list of KNOWN items (100+ that won't likely change) from the C# back-end, or to just build the list from the front-end using asp:ListItem?

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDocType" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="AMENDMENT" Value="AMENDMENT"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="AMENDMENT ABSTRACT" Value="AMENDMENT ABSTRACT"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="BID AND BID RESPONSE" Value="BID AND BID RESPONSE"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="BOND" Value="BOND"></asp:ListItem>
    .
    .
    .
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Of course is better from front-side versus code behind. But these 100+values are known?

Comment: If these values are dynamic you have to ask which is the best way to bind a dropdownlist!

Comment: Yes, they are known values. Edited to show that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if the list likely won't change, I'd still recommend the binding approach simply as a matter of separating the concerns.

The list is business data.  It may be static, unchanging business data, but it's still data.  And data doesn't really belong in the UI.  The UI is simply an expression of *presenting* that data.

The data itself should live with other business data.

Comment: BRAVO! nice response and fully agreed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using server side control , it must bind in the server side , if you want to bind the data in the front end, use HTML Control Tag :

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

But if it is more than 100 , store in the database and bind in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) plugin or [textext](http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/ajax-with-autocomplete.html) for ajax autocomplete textbox.

Comment: Obligatory: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif  Reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/148400